# C++ typedef in a class

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I use this C++ code for storing x to the variable val.

```
class Hello
{
  int val;
public:
  Hello(int x) : val(x) {}
};
```

However, when I saw this code, I cannot see how Super can store value t or o.

```
template<typename T>
class K : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;
public:
    K() : Super() { }
    K(T* t) : Super(t) { }
    K(K<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
};
```

How does this code work?

Comment: A little clarification on what the confusing part is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could've been written as

```
template<typename T>
class K : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
public:
    K() : std::auto_ptr<T>() { }
    K(T* t) : std::auto_ptr<T>(t) { }
    K(K<T>& o) : std::auto_ptr<T>(o) { }
};
```

Which is just more verbose to initialize the base class. A typedef is cleaner most of the time if you have to deal with templated base classes.

Answer (score 2):

It's because class `K` inherits from `std::auto_ptr<T>`. What is happening is that the constructors `K(T* t)` and `K(K<T>& o)` call the parent constructor `std::auto_ptr<T>(...)`, which is also called `Super` thanks to typedef.

Answer (score 1):

The typedef `typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;` means that Super is an auto_ptr of type T. The empty constructor of K initializes Super, if a pointer of type T is given then Super is initialized to be an auto_ptr managing it, and if a reference to K with type T is given then this is passed to Super.

Answer (score 1):

The `auto_ptr<T>` base class that you are deriving from is a container for an element of class `T`. That base class has (at least) the constructors defined that you are calling:

The baseclass *could* be defined like this (actually, it is not, but this constructor-definitions might give you a picture):

```
template<typename T>
class auto_ptr {
    T* value;
  public:
    auto_ptr() : value(NULL) {}
    auto_ptr(T* t) : value(t) { }
    auto_ptr(auto_ptr<T>& other) : value(other.value) {}
};
```

So, `auto_ptr<T>` *holds* a value of type `T`. And the three defined constructors take care of:

- empty/standard constrcution
- construction from a raw pointer
- copy of the container

So, and then by telling in you class, that you give `Super` the name `std::auto_ptr<T>` that is just an abbreviation to call the respective base class constructor. You could have written

```
template<typename T>
class K : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
public:
    K() : std::auto_ptr<T>() { }
    K(T* t) : std::auto_ptr<T>(t) { }
    K(K<T>& o) : std::auto_ptr<T>(o) { }
};
```

because you are now directly calling the base class constructors. And those we have defined before (and in "real life" are defined with more sense then I did here).

*PS: `auto_ptr<>` is nice as long as you have not seen `unique_ptr<>`. `auto_ptr<>`s "bad guy" is it's copy-constructor. Watch out for C++0x...*